# Duplicate home / front page - available on two urls

Tags: 7, views

I created a view and set it as the front page; its path is */front*.

The front page is accessible as https://example.com/ and https://example.com/front. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

It's normal Drupal behavior to have front page accessible by it's original path.

What I would recommend in the case is installing the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module and configuring it to 301 redirect from `/front` to `/`.

Comment: Global redirect module is good for this however it requires no configuration to do what the OP needs. Just enable the module and you're good to go.

Comment: Also, with this solution there is no need to add the front page to robots.txt